# Extraction Of Specifically Matched Sub Strings From A String

Tags: java, string, extract

I have a `String` and a `List<String>`.  I desire to extract from the `String` the contents of my `List<String` including two characters before and after.

I have reviewed examples from `StackOverflow`.  There is no delimiter, there is no demarcation that indicates the match is delineated in any form.  I have asked and reviewed answer using RegEx and believe that may be the way to do it but how is my question.

If I have `String toParse = "Parse this to grab the &@ClaimNumber@& variable";` and my `List<String>` contains `ClaimNumber`, is there an object oriented solution?

Comment: It sounds like the regex you want is just `(..ClaimNumber..)` Or possibly `(.?.?ClaimNumber.?.?)` to catch cases with 0 or 1 leading/trailing characters.

Comment: @CollinD Yes, that would be correct.  The variable `ClaimNumber` contained in my `List<String>` including  two characters before and after.

Answer (score 1):

The following method will do it, following the [suggestion by CollinD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497082/extraction-of-specifically-matched-sub-strings-from-a-string#comment68238253_40497082), with the addition of correctly quoting the dynamic search values:

```
private static List<String> extract(String input, List<String> keywords) {
    StringJoiner regex = new StringJoiner("|");
    for (String keyword : keywords)
        regex.add(".." + Pattern.quote(keyword) + "..");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex.toString()).matcher(input); m.find(); )
        result.add(m.group());
    return result;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(extract("Parse this to grab the &@ClaimNumber@& variable",
                           Arrays.asList("ClaimNumber")));
System.out.println(extract("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
                           Arrays.asList("fox", "i")));
```

*Output*

```
[&@ClaimNumber@&]
[quick, n fox j]
```